# Permutations of 3 elements within 6 positions

Tags: arrays, r, combinatorics, permute

I'm looking to permute (or combine) `c("a","b","c")` within six positions under the condition to have always sequences with alternate elements, e.g `abcbab`.

Permutations could easily get with:

```
abc<-c("a","b","c")
permutations(n=3,r=6,v=abc,repeats.allowed=T)
```

I think is not possible to do that with gtools, and I've been trying to design a function for that -even though I think it may already exist.

Comment: Which is it, permute or combine? The two have significant differences.

Comment: I doubt a tool will exist for this specific problem, you'll need to generate candidate combinations/permutations and test/filter manually.

Comment: @r2evans, I know R is not the space for this, but this problem has got recursion written all over it

Comment: @JosephWood, a lot of these selective-permutation examples can be resolved (not-inefficiently) by well-designed recursive functions, true. I don't think R does tail-recursion "efficiently" (at least, not the same as some other languages), so I tend towards more iterative or looping heuristics over recursive, but you're right that the solution might be elegantly addressed with recursion.

Comment: @r2evans, I agree with you. To be honest, I vaguely remember you being a master at recursion, and my comment was to nudge you to conjure up some recursion magic.

Comment: Thanks for the vote :-). I think recursion is actually not the best option ... one problem with a recursive approach is that it has the potential to draw randomness at each function call, inefficient (perhaps just in R). It's best to call as much randomness as we need *up front*.

Comment: (My last comment shows my initial incorrect thought that this was intended to be a *sampling* problem, not specifically looking for the *complete set* of combinations. Recursion could be more of a player, though admittedly I think the all-at-once approach I have in my answer is going to be faster and still complete.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're looking for permutations, `expand.grid` can work as well as `permutations`. But since you don't want like-neighbors, we can shorten the dimensionality of it considerably. I *think* this is legitimate random-wise!

Up front:

```
r <- replicate(6, seq_len(length(abc)-1), simplify=FALSE)
r[[1]] <- c(r[[1]], length(abc))
m <- t(apply(do.call(expand.grid, r), 1, cumsum) %% length(abc) + 1)
m[] <- abc[m]
dim(m)
# [1] 96  6
head(as.data.frame(cbind(m, apply(m, 1, paste, collapse = ""))))
#   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6     V7
# 1    b    c    a    b    c    a bcabca
# 2    c    a    b    c    a    b cabcab
# 3    a    b    c    a    b    c abcabc
# 4    b    a    b    c    a    b babcab
# 5    c    b    c    a    b    c cbcabc
# 6    a    c    a    b    c    a acabca
```

---

Walk-through:

- since you want all recycled permutations of it, we can use `gtools::permutations`, or we can use `expand.grid` ... I'll use the latter, I don't know if it's much faster, but it does a short-cut I need (more later)
- when dealing with constraints like this, I like to expand on the indices of the vector of values
- however, since we don't want neighbors to be the same, I thought that instead of each row of values being the straight index, we `cumsum` them; by using this, we can control the ability of the cumulative sum to re-reach the same value ... by removing `0` and `length(abc)` from the list of possible values, we remove the possibility of (a) never staying the same, and (b) never increasing actually one vector-length (repeating the same value); as a walk-through:

  ```
  head(expand.grid(1:3, 1:2, 1:2, 1:2, 1:2, 1:2), n = 6)
  #   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6
  # 1    1    1    1    1    1    1
  # 2    2    1    1    1    1    1
  # 3    3    1    1    1    1    1
  # 4    1    2    1    1    1    1
  # 5    2    2    1    1    1    1
  # 6    3    2    1    1    1    1
  ```

  Since the first value can be all three values, it's `1:3`, but each additional is intended to be 1 or 2 away from it.

  ```
  head(t(apply(expand.grid(1:3, 1:2, 1:2, 1:2, 1:2, 1:2), 1, cumsum)), n = 6)
  #      Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6
  # [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
  # [2,]    2    3    4    5    6    7
  # [3,]    3    4    5    6    7    8
  # [4,]    1    3    4    5    6    7
  # [5,]    2    4    5    6    7    8
  # [6,]    3    5    6    7    8    9
  ```

  okay, that doesn't seem that useful (since it goes beyond the length of the vector), so we can invoke the modulus operator and a shift (since modulus returns 0-based, we want 1-based):

  ```
  head(t(apply(expand.grid(1:3, 1:2, 1:2, 1:2, 1:2, 1:2), 1, cumsum) %% 3 + 1), n = 6)
  #      Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6
  # [1,]    2    3    1    2    3    1
  # [2,]    3    1    2    3    1    2
  # [3,]    1    2    3    1    2    3
  # [4,]    2    1    2    3    1    2
  # [5,]    3    2    3    1    2    3
  # [6,]    1    3    1    2    3    1
  ```
- To verify this works, we can do a `diff` across each row and look for `0`:

  ```
  m <- t(apply(expand.grid(1:3, 1:2, 1:2, 1:2, 1:2, 1:2), 1, cumsum) %% 3 + 1)
  any(apply(m, 1, diff) == 0)
  # [1] FALSE
  ```
- to *automate* this to an arbitrary vector, we enlist the help of `replicate` to generate the list of possible vectors:

  ```
  r <- replicate(6, seq_len(length(abc)-1), simplify=FALSE)
  r[[1]] <- c(r[[1]], length(abc))
  str(r)
  # List of 6
  #  $ : int [1:3] 1 2 3
  #  $ : int [1:2] 1 2
  #  $ : int [1:2] 1 2
  #  $ : int [1:2] 1 2
  #  $ : int [1:2] 1 2
  #  $ : int [1:2] 1 2
  ```

  and then `do.call` to expand it.
- one you have the matrix of indices,

  ```
  head(m)
  #      Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6
  # [1,]    2    3    1    2    3    1
  # [2,]    3    1    2    3    1    2
  # [3,]    1    2    3    1    2    3
  # [4,]    2    1    2    3    1    2
  # [5,]    3    2    3    1    2    3
  # [6,]    1    3    1    2    3    1
  ```

  and then replace each index with the vector's value:

  ```
  m[] <- abc[m]
  head(m)
  #      Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6
  # [1,] "b"  "c"  "a"  "b"  "c"  "a" 
  # [2,] "c"  "a"  "b"  "c"  "a"  "b" 
  # [3,] "a"  "b"  "c"  "a"  "b"  "c" 
  # [4,] "b"  "a"  "b"  "c"  "a"  "b" 
  # [5,] "c"  "b"  "c"  "a"  "b"  "c" 
  # [6,] "a"  "c"  "a"  "b"  "c"  "a"
  ```
- and then we `cbind` the united string (via `apply` and `paste`)

---

Performance:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

microbenchmark(
  tidy1 = {
    gtools::permutations(n = 3, r = 6, v = abc, repeats.allowed = TRUE) %>% 
      data.frame() %>% 
      unite(united, sep = "", remove = FALSE) %>%
      filter(!str_detect(united, "([a-c])\\1"))
  },
  tidy2 = {
      filter(unite(data.frame(gtools::permutations(n = 3, r = 6, v = abc, repeats.allowed = TRUE)),
                   united, sep = "", remove = FALSE),
             !str_detect(united, "([a-c])\\1"))
  },
  base = {
    r <- replicate(6, seq_len(length(abc)-1), simplify=FALSE)
    r[[1]] <- c(r[[1]], length(abc))
    m <- t(apply(do.call(expand.grid, r), 1, cumsum) %% length(abc) + 1)
    m[] <- abc[m]
  },
  times=10000
)
# Unit: microseconds
#   expr      min        lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
#  tidy1 1875.400 2028.8510 2446.751 2165.651 2456.051 12790.901 10000
#  tidy2 1745.402 1875.5015 2284.700 2000.051 2278.101 50163.901 10000
#   base  796.701  871.4015 1020.993  919.801 1021.801  7373.901 10000
```

I tried the infix (non-`%>%`) tidy2 version just for kicks, and though I was confident it would theoretically be faster, I didn't realize it would shave over 7% off the run-times. (The 50163 is likely R garbage-collecting, not "real".) *The price we pay for readability/maintainability.*

Answer (score 3):

There are probably cleaner methods, but here ya go:

```
abc <- letters[1:3]

library(tidyverse)

res <- gtools::permutations(n = 3, r = 6, v = abc, repeats.allowed = TRUE) %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  unite(united, sep = "", remove = FALSE) %>%
  filter(!str_detect(united, "([a-c])\\1"))

head(res)  

  united X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
1 ababab  a  b  a  b  a  b
2 ababac  a  b  a  b  a  c
3 ababca  a  b  a  b  c  a
4 ababcb  a  b  a  b  c  b
5 abacab  a  b  a  c  a  b
6 abacac  a  b  a  c  a  c
```

If you want a vector, you can use `res$united` or add `%>% pull(united)` as an additional step at the end of the pipes above.

Comment: No worries, the `%>%` symbol is a pipe from the `magrittr` package([info here](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/)). I've updated the answer to save the result as `res`

Comment: The problem is that we get 1 column data.frame instead of six to be able to manipulate data. Do you know how to do it ? `separate` probably?

Comment: no need - `unite` has a `remove` argument, you can just pass `FALSE` to it and you'll keep your inputted columns

Comment: @fina, the questions you are asking in the comments are not really appropriate. I would suggest reading the documentation and play around with stuff. It may be painful, but trust me, it is soooo worth it. Also, nice answer zack!

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the comments. I'll do it,