# Permutations of 3 elements within 6 positions: one equal neighbour

Tags: arrays, r, combinatorics, permute

Taking into account the answers in this post [Permutations of 3 elements within 6 positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53566191/permutations-of-3-elements-within-6-positions/53566390?noredirect=1#comment93999041_53566390), I think it's worth to open a new discussion about how ordering the elements.

The first condition was to have always sequences with alternate elements:

```
#   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6     V7
# 1    b    c    a    b    c    a bcabca
# 2    c    a    b    c    a    b cabcab
# 3    a    b    c    a    b    c abcabc
# 4    b    a    b    c    a    b babcab
# 5    c    b    c    a    b    c cbcabc
# 6    a    c    a    b    c    a acabca
```

However, the rest of the permutations could have value even if there is **one coincidence of elements** in like-neighbour restriction. For instance:

```
    #   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6 Coincidence  
    # 1    b    b    a    b    c    a     -->[bb]
    # 2    c    c    b    c    a    b     -->[cc] 
    # 3    a    b    c    a    a    c     -->[aa] 
    # 4    b    a    c    c    a    b     -->[cc]
```

Is it possible to use expand.grid for that too?

Comment: fina, that seems vague to me. Are you trying to allow 1 repeat but no more? Or are you completely removing the like-neighbor constraint from the previous question?

Comment: I'll reformulate the question, but I think that the like-neighbour constraint must be partially removed if we want to get only one repeated element for each sequence, getting e.g: `aabcba` ; `bbabca` or `acbbab` (in the middle of the sequence). Now all sequences have alternate elements except one that is repeated aa (first one), bb and bb. I was wondering if the same method could be used or not.

Comment: Do you mean: have *at most 1* repeat (like-neighbors)?

Comment: yes, only one, as in the example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's "only one more", then I suggest the simplest way to *allow* it is to *force* it.

Using the start from the previous question:

```
r <- replicate(6, seq_len(length(abc)-1), simplify=FALSE)
r[[1]] <- c(r[[1]], length(abc))
```

We now copy this single list (that is passed to `expand.grid`) and replace each of the 2nd through last elements with 0. Recall that we are using these numbers with `cumsum` to change from the previous value, so replacing `1:2` with `0` means that we are forcing the next element to be the same.

```
rs <- lapply(seq_len(length(r)-1) + 1, function(i) { r[[i]] <- 0; r; })
#            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ or: seq_len(length(r))[-1]
str(rs[1:2])
# List of 2
#  $ :List of 6
#   ..$ : int [1:3] 1 2 3
#   ..$ : num 0             <--- the second letter will repeat
#   ..$ : int [1:2] 1 2
#   ..$ : int [1:2] 1 2
#   ..$ : int [1:2] 1 2
#   ..$ : int [1:2] 1 2
#  $ :List of 6
#   ..$ : int [1:3] 1 2 3
#   ..$ : int [1:2] 1 2
#   ..$ : num 0             <--- the third letter will repeat
#   ..$ : int [1:2] 1 2
#   ..$ : int [1:2] 1 2
#   ..$ : int [1:2] 1 2
### other rs's are similar
```

We can verify that this works as we think it should:

```
# rs[[1]] repeats the first 2
m <- t(apply(do.call(expand.grid, rs[[1]]), 1, cumsum) %% length(abc) + 1)
m[] <- abc[m]
head(as.data.frame(cbind(m, apply(m, 1, paste, collapse = ""))), n=3)
#   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6     V7
# 1    b    b    c    a    b    c bbcabc
# 2    c    c    a    b    c    a ccabca
# 3    a    a    b    c    a    b aabcab

# rs[[3]] repeats the 3rd-4th
m <- t(apply(do.call(expand.grid, rs[[3]]), 1, cumsum) %% length(abc) + 1)
m[] <- abc[m]
head(as.data.frame(cbind(m, apply(m, 1, paste, collapse = ""))), n=3)
#   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6     V7
# 1    b    c    a    a    b    c bcaabc
# 2    c    a    b    b    c    a cabbca
# 3    a    b    c    c    a    b abccab
```

From here, let's automate it by putting all of these into one list and `lapply`ing them.

```
rs <- c(list(r), rs)
rets <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, c(stringsAsFactors=FALSE, lapply(rs, function(r) {
  m <- t(apply(do.call(expand.grid, r), 1, cumsum) %% length(abc) + 1)
  m[] <- abc[m]
  as.data.frame(cbind(m, apply(m, 1, paste, collapse = "")), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
})))
head(rets)
#   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6     V7
# 1    b    c    a    b    c    a bcabca
# 2    c    a    b    c    a    b cabcab
# 3    a    b    c    a    b    c abcabc
# 4    b    a    b    c    a    b babcab
# 5    c    b    c    a    b    c cbcabc
# 6    a    c    a    b    c    a acabca
tail(rets)
#     Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6     V7
# 331    b    c    b    a    c    c bcbacc
# 332    c    a    c    b    a    a cacbaa
# 333    a    b    a    c    b    b abacbb
# 334    b    a    c    b    a    a bacbaa
# 335    c    b    a    c    b    b cbacbb
# 336    a    c    b    a    c    c acbacc
```

Walkthrough of additional steps:

- `rs <- c(list(r), rs)` makes the first (non-repeating `r`) an enclosed list, then prepends it to the `rs` list.
- `lapply(rs, function(r) ...)` does the `...` from the previous question once for each element in the `rs` list. I named it `r` inside the anon-function to make it perfectly clear (inside the function) that each time it gets a new `r`, it does exactly the same steps as the last question.
- `do.call(rbind.data.frame, c(stringsAsFactors=FALSE, ...` because each return from the `lapply` will be a data.frame, and we want to combine them into a single frame. I prefer no factors, but you can choose otherwise if you need. (Instead of `rbind.data.frame`, you could use `data.table::rbindlist` or `dplyr::bind_rows`, both without `stringsAsFactors`.)

Now the first 96 rows have no repeats, then the remaining five batches of 48 rows each (total 336 rows) have one repeat each. We "know" that 48 is the right number for each of the repeat-once lists, since by changing one of the positions from "`1 2`" possible to "`0`" (from 2 to 1 possible value) we halve the total number of possible combinations (`96 / 2 == 48`).

If for some reason your *next* question asks how to expand this to allow *two* repeats ... then I wouldn't necessarily recommend brute-forcing *this* aspect of it: there are 6 or 10 possible combinations (depending on if `"aaa"` is allowed) of repeats, and I would much prefer to go to a more programmatic handling than this brute-force appending of the one-constraint.

Comment: There is no next question and I agree with you, right now it seems the fastest way to solve the problem, but not the most convenient way to go ahead.

Comment: I just want to say that you're a master.